# Dell XPS 13 fails to boot; grub-install installed grubx64.efi instead of shimx64.efi

Tags: boot, dell, grub-efi

I have a Dell XPS 13 running Ubuntu 18.04. The system **will not** boot the signed EFI bootloader `grubx64.efi`. The system only boots `shimx64.efi`.

Every time grub packages are updated, it triggers `grub-install`, which removes the working `shimx64.efi` boot entry and replaces it with a broken won't-boot `grubx64.efi` entry.

The error message shown during boot is:

```
Failed to open EFI\boot\grubx64.efi - Not found
Failed to load image EFI\boot\grubx64.efi: Not found
start_image() returned Not found
```

This is not because the file is not found, but because the Dell EFI boot does not trust the signature; it only trusts the shimx64.efi signature.

How can I get `grub-install` to install the correct bootloader?

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I had the `shim` package installed, but *not* `shim-signed`.

Installing `shim-signed` fixed my problem.

`grub-install` now installs shimx64.efi instead of grubx64.efi. Having the package `shim` installed is insufficient.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with the XPS 13 7390, Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.
I deactivated Secure Boot, switched to AHCI (from RAID) and broke the Windows on booting,..and when I was able to use Ubuntu in Live mode, I got the error you had during installation.

What worked out for me is to format the whole disk(make sure you did your backup before), and create a small partition of 500MB 'EFI System Partition' as Primary', as demonstrated here: [No EFI System Partition option for Ubuntu 18.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1128810/no-efi-system-partition-option-for-ubuntu-18-10#answer-1128817)

The remaining partitions can be organized in your usual way.
Simplest is to have one partition ext4 as root `/` with remaining disk space.
That's it!

More detail:
In my case, what I did, is the first time during installation by selecting the Option `Erase disk and install Ubuntu`, and I got the same error.
Then, I saw somewhere saying to select the option `Something else` and from there, I created:

- Small partition of 500MB 'EFI System Partition' as Primary' as explained earlier and (you might need to delete it and then re-create it)
- Created a ext4 partition to use all remaining disk space as root /

Here is the example of how it looks like at the end
[image]

Then continued with installation, and surprisingly, it worked!

For the disk partitioning, Redhat(https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/installation_guide/s2-diskpartrecommend-x86) recommends that you create the following partitions for x86, AMD64, and Intel 64 systems:

```
A swap partition
A /boot partition
A / partition
A home partition
A /boot/efi partition (EFI System Partition) - only on systems with UEFI firmware 

A swap partition (at least 256 MB) — Swap partitions support virtual memory: data is written to a swap partition when there is not enough RAM to store the data your system is processing.
```