# No EFI System Partition option for Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: uefi

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 18.10 on a new not partitioned HDD (using a VMWare machine). I try with manual partitioning to create the EFI System Partition but there is no *EFI System Partition* option (or other option containing the *EFI* word). I tried with 100M, 300M, 500M, 512M sizes but no luck. What's the solution for this?

PS: the similar question related to Ubuntu 15.10 doesn't help

Comment: hi. I'm a bit surprized by your wording here, maybe I'm missunderstanding, would you mind editing your post to go through what you expect, what unfortunately is the case instead and a picture of the screen you're seeing durring  what I assume is the install process from the Live  CD? (if you choose "try ubuntu" instead of "install ubuntu" while booting you'll be able to run the same install process from the desktop icon but also take screencap, with the screencap app and upload it here.)

Comment: Are you using USB installable stick for Ubuntu 18.10? You may refer  [Ubuntu 18.04.02 Bionic Beaver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1125710/what-does-it-mean-to-make-a-bootable-liveusb/1125721#1125721) to prepare USB stick with UEFI (non CSM) and “Partition scheme” to “GPT”. Although this procedure is for Ubuntu 18.04, but you can use the same procedure to prepare USB bootable stick for Ubuntu 18.10.

Comment: As you imagine I try the installation process at PC boot time. I’m simply creating a VMWare machine with Ubuntu, nothing fancy besides the manual partitioning.

Comment: I use an iso file with VMWare.

Comment: My whole purpose is to play with the manual partitioning feature.

Comment: Are you using a VMware program to load your ISO image? If so, can you please give some more details @adrhc?

Comment: What is your VMWare version? Are you using workstation or Server/ESXi?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## The EFI System Partition (ESP)

The requirements for the ESP partition are:

1. It must be a primary partition (relevant only for MBR based partition table)
2. It must be a FAT32 partition
3. The boot flag must be set

## Ubuntu 18.10 Installation Something Else option

Before we get to the Something else option and manual partition of the hard drive, we have to make sure the Live USB/DVD or the ISO (in case of virtual machines) boot in the UEFI mode and not the legacy BIOS mode. I will describe both below:

### Live USB/DVD/ISO in BIOS Legacy Mode

The first clue that the computer booted in BIOS Legacy mode is from the Live USB/DVD/ISO boot screen. If you see:

[image]

Then you have booted in BIOS mode!

In this mode, the installer does not show an option to create an ESP partition. There is no ESP option because in this mode one does not need an ESP partition.

[image]

If you get this, cancel the installation and figure out how to boot from the Live USB/DVD/ISO in the UEFI mode. (*More on this for virtual machines later in the answer.*)

### Live USB/DVD/ISO in UEFI Mode

When you boot the Live USB/DVD/ISO using the UEFI mode you will see:

[image]

As you see below in this mode, the installer will show an option to create an ESP partition:

**Note:** It may say **EFI Boot Partiion** in some version of Ubuntu instead of  **EFI System Partiion** as it shows in the image below.

[image]

Once you select the right partition type you will see:

[image]

After you click the OK button above you will get:

[image]

### Select UEFI boot in VMWare workstation

When you create the new VM and before you try to install Ubuntu, On VMware Workstation, go into **VM** > **Settings** > **Options** > **Advanced**, and check **Boot with EFI instead of BIOS**.

[image]

### Select UEFI boot in QEMU Virtual Machine Manager

I assume you have qemu virtual machine already setup in an Ubuntu host machine.
You need to install the virtual firmware for UEFI, ovmf in the host:

sudo apt install qemu ovmf

The next step must be done when you create a new virtual machine. Once the VM is created the boot option cannot be changed from BIOS to UEFI or vice versa. Check the box **Customize configuration before install** in Step 5:

[image]

In the Overview tab change the 'Firmware' field from BIOS to select the 'UEFI x86_64' option.

[image]

Then continue with the installation by clicking the green check mark at the top right <kbd>✅ Begin Installation</kbd>

Customize configuration before install

Hope this helps

Comment: It is for Ubuntu: it offers the EFI option.

Comment: @adrhc Prove that, e.g. include a screenshot in your question. You should also include a link to “the similar question related to Ubuntu 15.10” for reference.

Comment: Is your 3rd screenshot a joke? That white text is impossible to read.

Comment: @ScepticalJule no it is not joke. It is also not a screenshot. It a photograph, the best I could find at that time. I now have a proper screenshot. I hope you find this one readable.

Comment: you saved me another 4 days of tears! thx!

Comment: By Default EFI system was FAT maybe, so it was quick

Comment: @MayankGoyal I am happy that you found the answer useful.