# dual boot no efi system partition was found

Tags: 18.04

I am trying to install ubuntu along side with windows 10, following the official instructions given at [install ubuntu 18.04] https://vitux.com/how-to-install-ubuntu-18-04-along-with-windows-10/.

Here are screen shots of
storage management (I have shrunk the D disk for installing ubuntu):
[image]
the boot-up menu:

[image]
 and installation problem (`NO EFI System Partition was Found`):
[image]

Comment: Do you have a GPT disc or MBR?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

yes that's correct, when you customize your own partitions like you have done here you should create a small partition just for efi. So go back and create a partition in a size of 256MB and select efi as mount point.

You can read more about recommended partitions here
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace

Comment: I tried your suggest and then successfully installed Ubuntu. But I after rebooting, the login window only shows up the option for Ubuntu, not Windows for some reason. Do you have any idea of that? Thanks ahead

Comment: You can only have one ESP - efi system partition per drive. Best to have all drives as gpt and include the ESP as first partition, even if just data now. Then you can install to that drive later without major restructuring.  Ubuntu's installer only wants to install grub to first drive, usually sda or first NVMe drive. Boot-Repair may let you do a full reinstall of grub to sdb. I found work around during install if you do not have sda with ESP. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379

Comment: It seems I need to remove Ubuntu and reinstall it?

Comment: I found one way to log into windows: press F2 and select windows boot manager

Answer (score 5):

Your first partition is `FAT32` by format, but you must pick `EFI System Partition` in the "right click→use as…" Dialog. (which of course implies FAT32, but not the other way round)

[image]

Comment: What if i don't have the "EFI System Partition" option in the dropdown?

Comment: @joash Then you better check your BIOS thoroughly to enable (U)EFI. (PCs with non-EFI-support are prehistoric by now. Probably 10 years+++)  Maybe do repartioning again from scratch (botoing into live Linux 20,x comes with a `gparted` nowadays)...

Answer (score 4):

For the benefit of other people who got the dire "No EFI System Partition was found" warning during a "Something else" Ubuntu installation, I'd like to mention that this message will come up for a system configured for "Legacy" booting.  (I realize that this wasn't the poster of the question's problem.)

These days only older computers are configured for legacy (non-UEFI) booting, like my laptop built around 2011, which supports UEFI but is configured for legacy booting.  But if you do have an older computer and you got the warning, I'd recommend that you abort the installation and check the "BIOS" to see how your system is configured to boot.  If your system is configured to boot in legacy mode, then that's why you don't have an EFI system partition; you should be able to ignore the warning and proceed.

If your computer supports UEFI, then another option would be to create a UEFI system partition and tell the computer to boot in UEFI mode.  But that might not be a good idea for a dual-boot system, because the boot loader for other OS (usually Windows) might be confused and not know how to boot.  Personally, I wouldn't try to change the boot mode of a dual-boot (Ubuntu and Windows) system.

Comment: You may want to look at [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1128810/no-efi-system-partition-option-for-ubuntu-18-10/1128817#1128817) for how to determine "Legacy boot" from the Ubuntu installation USB. This does not work in Ubuntu 22.04, as the USB installer shows the same thing irrespective of which way (Legacy or UEFI) you boot the USB.

Answer (score 1):

My computer boots in legacy. I dual booted Linux mint and it displayed the same error. So I decided to take a risk and continue the installation and it was successful.

For older computers it is okay to ignore that and just move on.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Try changing the size of the RAM allocation (SWAP). The size of this partition should be at least equal to the size of system RAM.

Comment: Fresh installations of Ubuntu 18.04 do not have a swap partition by default. Instead they have a swap file.

Answer (score 0):

first of go into the hard disk drive's /boot/efi folder and rename the file grubx64.efi to mmx64.efi or other formats.

Reboot the machine and it should work.

This time when you are installing create a partition around 256MB and choose primary and EFI system partition. I hope this helps