# Receiving "No EFI System Partition was Found" while installing Ubuntu Budgie onto an empty external HDD

Tags: system-installation, uefi, usb-installation, budgie

My problem was solved by removing the other drives, and using the the target drive internally instead of externally. If anyone else sees this, I recommend this solution! Thanks to everyone who helped. :)

I was attempting to install Ubuntu Budgie onto a formatted NTFS external HDD using a USB flash, but I received the "No EFI System Partition was Found" error. I tried installing anyway, but it failed, as expected. I was following this guide: https://linuxhint.com/install-ubuntu-external-hard-drive/ and it didn't mention anything about an EFI partition. How can I avoid this error in future?

Comment: Are you planning on having the external drive as a multi-use drive where you have backup as well as an OS on it?  The instructions you are following show to remove the partition(s) off the external drive before installing it as it is going to be formatted in ext4 and not NTFS as Ubuntu will not run in NTFS.  It is also showing that you need to make sure that you choose the external drive for the bootloader install as well.  When you follow instructions for installation like this make sure not to skip any steps.

Comment: And Ubuntu by default install Grub (the bootloader) in the internal drive's ESP (EFI System Partition). Not a problem if you intend to boot in the same computer but it won't boot in a different (UEFI) computer. In order to install everything in the external drive it's better to disconnect or disable the internal one. Other than that the process is exactly the same. And, as above, it CAN'T be installed in a NTFS partition and it needs an ESP, so let the installer do it automatically because it "knows" a lot better than newbies.

Comment: @Terrance I tried using the format in the install guide, which worked fine, but it it still asked for the EFI partition.

Comment: @ChanganAuto So it shouldn't error if it's the main drive?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dual boot no efi system partition was found](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1144552/dual-boot-no-efi-system-partition-was-found)  It appears that the instructions there are missing the part of creating a small EFI Partition.

Comment: @Terrance Yep! That about answers it! I'll try and see if it works, and I'll get back to you with the results. :)

Comment: The Ubiquity installer only wants an ESP on first drive. And how you boot install media UEFI or BIOS is then how it installs. IF you partition in advance be sure to use gpt as that is the standard for UEFI, even though with Ubuntu you can use MBR. Some have reported that even a BIOS install asks for an ESP. Since Systems from 2012 are UEFI, they may be just assuming you will eventually convert to UEFI and then need the ESP. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379

Comment: @Terrance It turns put that the easiest way to create the pertition is by removing the other drives and fitting the one I was using an an internal drive. Everything is working great now. Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: @TigerDoodat Nice!  Glad it worked for you!  I have done that in the past too with multiple drives in a system and multiple OSes as to make things easier.  :-)