# /boot/efi and EFI windows partition

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, boot-repair, grub-efi

To install Ubuntu on GPT drive and UEFI I need a "EFI boot partition". So here is my partitions I would like to create for my Linux sytem

```
EFI boot partition (/boot/efi)
swap
/ (root)
/home
```

... however it didn't go smoothly (I think I run my usb stick with compatiblity features and in that case it didn't boot on "UEFI" mode ...) and I am using boot-repair on ubuntu.

I need dual boot with windows which uses the EFI windows partition (FAT32): **/dev/sda2**.

1. Should I mount my /boot/efi partition to this windows Fat32 partition or create a new one ?

Here is the **boot info** of my computer from boot repair.

http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/3wzFggFMh3/

This utility suggests:

```
GPT detected. Please create a BIOS-Boot partition (>1MB, unformatted filesystem, bios_grub flag). This can be performed via tools such as Gparted. Then try again.
Alternatively, you can retry after activating the [Separate /boot/efi partition:] option.
Gtk-Message: 15:14:21.079: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
(debug) reinstall grub2 place-in-MBR no-BIOS_boot (sda7)
```

2. Is this BIOS-Boot partition that I should create the partition /boot/efi above or the windows EFI partition ?
3. After the previous suggestion, this utility addresses:

   ```
   Grub-efi would not be selected by default because: no-win-efi
   ```

but what does it mean "no-win-efi" ? I have a windows EFi partition, it's my sda2 (ok I think I messed things up because it seems I erased the windows file with federa "bootlader" (I played dangereously with **grub-mkconfig** and it may have erased the windows file)) so I am afraid that if I use boot-repair I will lose windows.

4. If I really deleted the windows file on the windows EFi partition, may ubuntu help me to restore these files on this partition ?

Comment: See this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1128810/no-efi-system-partition-option-for-ubuntu-18-10/1128817#1128817) for a similar question. I am not sure yours is exactly the same. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: yeah thanks. Well it doesn't help except for confirming me that I should boot in UEFI mode which I do every time.

Comment: Ideally a computer should have only one EFI System Partition (ESP). Yours is `/dev/sda2`. It should be mounted as `/boot/efi` in Ubuntu. This is the answer to your Q1. I don't know that will solve your problem though. I don't know anything about Q2, Q3, and Q4.

Comment: Do not see Ubuntu, old install of Fedora still has UEFI boot entries & you show Mint. But you have to have Boot-Repair in BIOS mode for it to ask for bios_grub partition which is only required for BIOS boot. And you cannot dual boot using grub if Ubuntu is BIOS boot and Windows is UEFI Boot. Turn off fast start up in Windows. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions

Comment: ok yeah I created the boot info with Mint live, now I am using ubuntu live. Fedora is still there for the boot files and I am afraid they erased the windows files. I apy attention to boot the ubuntu drive with UEFI boot. I can't turn off fast boot in Windows since the latter doesn't boot (I can turn off in the BIOS)