# Force Ubuntu Installer to use only MBR -- no EFI

Tags: boot, system-installation, uefi, mbr

I have a UEFI-capable 64 bit system, but the existing Windows 7 is MBR.  I want to dual-boot with either Ubuntu 18.04 or 19.10 (don't care which).  The GUI install (bootable DVD) works fine in legacy mode, but installs Ubuntu such that it will boot only EFI.

I bought AOMEI Partition Assistant Pro, hoping to convert the Windows 7 system to EFI non-destructively, as they claim it will do.  The "non-destructive" conversion destroyed all boot capability.  I had to restore from backup.  (I do not have a W7 installation disk; The machine was bought "refurbished".)

Can the Ubuntu installer be forced to install an MBR/legacy bootable version?  If so, how?  (I also have a support request in to AOMEI to see if I can actually make the W7 system EFI bootable.)

Comment: Probably your UEFI-settings provide an option to boot only in legacy-mode.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I tell if my system was booted as EFI/UEFI or BIOS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162564/how-can-i-tell-if-my-system-was-booted-as-efi-uefi-or-bios)

Comment: How you boot install media UEFI or BIOS is then how it installs. You should get two boot options in UEFI boot one clearly UEFI:name of flash and other just "name of flash" which is then the BIOS option.

Comment: In addition to what @oldfred said above, see the pictures in this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1128810/no-efi-system-partition-option-for-ubuntu-18-10/1128817#1128817) to figure out if the Live USB is booting in Legacy or UEFI mode.

Comment: If you make your install disk using YUMI, (Non UEFI), you should end up with a BIOS only installer. https://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/

Comment: C.S.Cameron, the yumi setup looks good.  If you recast your comment as an answer, I will mark it as such.  User68186, identifying the boot mode post-binariam is very helpful.

Comment: I started out ignorant about UEFI vs. BIOS, and moved on boldly to confusion.  I finally got AOMEI Partition Assistant more or less right.  I had to convert BOTH hard drives to EFI, then unscramble drive letters in Windows 7.  It's functional, except for not making a bootable rescue disk correctly.  Now that Ubuntu 18.04 is installed and configured the way I want, Clonezilla takes care of the Windows rescue disk problem.